# Group by column which has value over 0

Tags: mysql

How would I write a query which will group my table rows by a column which has value over 0?

In my table i have 4 columns:

> 1. Name (Varchar(45))
> 2. Cash (DECIMAL(15,2))
> 3. Card(DECIMAL(15,2))
> 4. Wtransfer (DECIMAL(15,2))

I can show column sum like this:

```
SELECT sum(Cash) as gotovina, sum(Card) as kartice, sum(Wtransfer) as ziralno FROM tpos.dok_zag_d;
```

But I would like to show a new row for each payment method + another column named "sum" which holds the sum of payment method used.

Comment: Has value over 0 for which column cash,card or wtransfer? or there sum. You said want to group by but for which column. Please give the complete details.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the 3 columns

```
SELECT sum(Cash) as gotovina, sum(Card) as kartice, sum(Wtransfer) as ziralno 
    , sum(Cash) + sum(Card) + sum(Wtransfer)  as summ
FROM tpos.dok_zag_d;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want a `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'Cash' AS payment_method, SUM(Cash) AS summ FROM tpos.dok_zag_d
UNION
SELECT 'Card', SUM(Card) FROM tpos.dok_zag_d
UNION
SELECT 'Wtransfer', SUM(Wtransfer) FROM tpos.dok_zag_d
```